# Excel VBA SlicerCaches - Application defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to understand why I'm getting an application defined error on the first line of this code? "For i = 1...."

```
Sub SlicerSelectToday()

Dim todaystring As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WkEnd11").SlicerItems.Count
            If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WkEnd11").SlicerItems(i).Value <> Format$(Date + (7 - Weekday(Date)), "yyyy-mm-dd") Then 'if date doesn't match then
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WkEnd11").SlicerItems(i).Selected = False 'deselects all other dates
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

What's funny is this code on a different slicer works fine:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ReportDt").SlicerItems.Count 'looping through all items
If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ReportDt").SlicerItems(i).Value <> Format$(Date - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") Then 'if date doesn't match then
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ReportDt").SlicerItems(i).Selected = False 'deselects all other dates
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure the `ActiveWorkbook` actually has a `SlicerCache` with that name?  Try for example, `Dim sc As SlicerCache`, `Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slilcer_WkEnd11")`. Does this throw an error?

Comment: When running this in VBA the Macros box pops up

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Did you add those two lines to `Sub SlicerSelectToday()`?

Comment: Yes - looks like it couldn't find the slicer - I'm going to delete it and recreate to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: So it looks like one of the slicers is based on a power pivot - not sure how to update the code